# Why is the determinant of the triangular matrix the diagonals?

Tags: linear-algebra

I am reading this proof and I do not follow. Can someone flash it out a bit and provide an example?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An example  hopefully illuminating: we expand by the last row the following $4\times4$ determinant:

\begin{align}
\begin{vmatrix}
a_{11} & a_{12} &a_{13} & a_{14}\\
0 & a_{22} &a_{23} & a_{24} \\
0 & 0 &a_{33} & a_{34} \\
0 & 0 & 0 & a_{44}
\end{vmatrix}
& =-0\cdot
\begin{vmatrix}
  a_{12} &a_{13} & a_{14}\\
 a_{22} &a_{23} & a_{24} \\
0 &  a_{33} & a_{34} 
\end{vmatrix} +0\cdot
\begin{vmatrix}
  a_{11} &a_{13} & a_{14}\\
 0 &a_{23} & a_{24} \\
0 &  a_{33} & a_{34}
\end{vmatrix} -0\cdot 
\begin{vmatrix}
  a_{11} &a_{12} & a_{14}\\
 0 &a_{22} & a_{24} \\
0 &  0 & a_{34}
\end{vmatrix}\\&\phantom{{}={}}
+a_{44}\cdot
\begin{vmatrix}
  a_{11} &a_{12} & a_{13}\\
 0 &a_{22} & a_{23} \\
0 &  0 & a_{33}
\end{vmatrix} =a_{44}\cdot(a_{11}a_{22}a_{33})\\[1ex]&\text{by the inductive hypothesis}.
\end{align}

Answer (score 1):

Use reduction of the determinant on the first column, you'll find the first term of the diagonal times the minor of the determinant. Iterate the process, you'll find that it's the product of the diagonal terms.